# Cloud template files for multiple systems/targets?

Tags: cloud, templates

I've got an Ubuntu VM instance on Google Cloud Platform and am setting it up to my needs. What troubles me is the `/etc/cloud/templates` directory. In there, there are templates not only for my own VM instance, but also for other OSs.

[image: Please see the listing]

What's the purpose of adding templates for other OSs?

Comment: It's just the way `cloud-init` is packaged, along with OS-specific templates. if you believe this is a bug, file it over on their bug tracker. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bugs

Comment: @popey another source repo for `cloud-init` I fount at https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init I wonder is this repo just a mirror of the one you provided or what correlation between them?

Comment: It says right on that github page "Official upstream for the cloud-init: cloud instance initialization" and Find a bug? Report bugs on Launchpad, with the link I provided.